# How can I quickly reference a file from git status without the full path

Tags: git

I typically have a few files I'm working on in a given commit and sometimes I want to commit only some of them or perhaps roll a few back. I end up having to type out most of the file by hand especially, if the files are in the same path.

```
git status
...
   modified: src/foo/Views/bar/helloWorld.html
   modified: src/foo/Views/bar/helloCrazyWorld.html
   modified: src/foo/Views/bar/goodByeCruelWorld.html
   modified: src/foo/Controllers/bar/hello
   modified: src/foo/Controllers/bar/goodbye
```

Ignoring the terrible and nonsensical directory structure. What is the best way to quick specify that I want to `git checkout src/foo/Controllers/bar/hello` without actually typing out the full path?

Assume there might be similar directories like the following so that tab-completion isn't always more viable than just typing.

```
src/fob
src/foo/Views/bad
```

It would be nice to be able to say `git checkout #4` and have it checkout the 4th item. Or `git commit #2` to commit the second.

Comment: Depending on how many similar names you have in your file structure, wildcards may or may not help. You can, for example, `add src/foo/C*/bar/h*`, or `add src/foo/Controllers/bar` (which will also add `goodbye`), or anything that like. Anything you can do with globbing expressions on the regular cli seems to work with `add`. Additionally, you can always pipe input to `add` from a grep or sed expression.

Comment: `git status --porcelain > file` (or `--short` / `-s`), then edit commands into the file and `sh file`.  I also use snarf-n-barf (mouse cut and paste) for this a lot, although it leads to paste-o's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most decent shells these days support the `**` wildcard which will match multiple subdirectory levels. You could do this, for example:

```
git status **/goodbye
```

Works with bash and zsh. I don't use other shells, but I'd be surprised if anything modern lacked the capability.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this on the CLI (unless you wrote it yourself).  Those sorts of use cases are what GUIs excel at.  [Try a bunch](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) until you find one you like.

Comment: I'm not really interested in using a gui. Thanks though!